# How to import csv file to sqlite using vscode?

Tags: sqlite, csv, visual-studio-code

I am just a beginner programmer wanted to try using sqlite. But with the help of VScode, I can't import files into my database

Comment: Could you provide more information ? What is your intent ? Import the csv data to sqllite ?